# How to treat users stories which were almost completed at the previous sprint?

Tags: scrum, estimation, user-stories, sprint, story-points

How to treat users stories which were almost completed at previous sprint but didn't meet Definition of Done due to testers were late for some reason.

Suppose one of those stories was 5 story points, so how to treat it for the next sprint? Also as 5? Or reestimate it as 1/2?

Comment: Welcome to PMSE! This question seems like a duplicate of a question that has already been asked and answered. If your question is materially different in some way, please update your question and flag it for re-opening by the community.

Comment: See Also: https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/15753/4271

Comment: As a quick summary, velocity doesn't mean "work completed on the project." It's a metric for *forecasting* per-iteration team capacity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You re-estimate them. The difference is "lost", it's not part of this sprint's velocity, because it was not done. The re-estimated story can be in the next sprint, but does not have to be.

You said "the testers were late". Does that mean testers are outside of your Scrum team? Then your Definition of Done is not working out. The development team should be able to turn stories into finished product increments *on their own*. If they cannot do so, then something is not right.

Comment: the testers are part of the team. But developer finished the task at the last moment of sprint, so tester just had no chance ... but he tried, but was too late (((( so sad...

Comment: Well, then it's easy. The team did not complete the story. It does not matter in which state it was last or who exactly in the team failed to finish it. My first paragraph applies. Re-estimate what's left, the difference in points is lost.

Comment: and should be velocity of previous sprint treated as completely without this task? Or need to count somehow?

Comment: No, the story was not finished, so no points were gained from it in the sprint.